# error: The argument type ‘..’ can't be assigned to the parameter type ‘..’

Tags: dart

I am trying to call a function that accepts another function as the argument.

When I try to generalize using Generics, I get the below error

> Error: The argument type ‘..’ can't be assigned to the parameter type ‘..’.

```dart
class MyType {}
typedef MyFunctionType = void Function(Function <MyValue extends MyType> (MyValue?, MyValue));

class MyClass <MyValue extends MyType> {

  late MyFunctionType myFunc;

  MyClass(this.myFunc) {
    (observer) => this.newValues(observer.oldValue,observer.oldValue);
  }


  MyClass <MyValue> _select(MyValue Function(MyValue) selector)  {
    var observerFunc = (oldValue,newValue) {

    };
    return MyClass((observer) => this.observe(observerFunc));
  }


  void observe(MyFunctionType func){
    this.myFunc = func;
  }

  void newValues(MyValue oldValue, MyValue newValue) {
    // TODO Add functionality
  }
}
```

The below is the error

```
error: The argument type 'void Function(dynamic Function<MyValue₀ extends MyType>(MyValue, MyValue))' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic Function<MyValue extends MyType>(MyValue, MyValue))'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [dartTry] test/Params2Arguments.dart:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though my example is much simpler:

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;

  Answer(this.selectHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        ...
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error on the line assigning the `onPressed` function was:

**The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.  *dart(argument_type_not_assignable)***

Adding the void type to my function property did the trick, though this requires adding parentheses:

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() selectHandler;
  ...
}
```